# Best free PDF generation library for complex layouts

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Which is the best free library (for whatewer programming language) for generating PDF with complex layouts (many pictures, text in arbitrary positions etc)? It should be best suited for drawing, not report generation. I'm considering prawn, but not shure if there exist a better solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Haru Free PDF](http://libharu.sourceforge.net/) . Also see this [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software#Creators_5)